# SQLAlchemy equivalent for Django `__` subquerying

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm pretty new to SQLAlchemy (specifically with Flask). I'd like to replicate a subquery that would look like this on Django:

```py
Blah3.objects.filter(id=1, blah2__blah1__attr=1).exists()
```

where the models look like:

```
class Blah1(models.Model): ...

class Blah2(models.Model):
    blah1 = models.ForeignKey(Blah1)

class Blah3(models.Model):
    blah2 = models.ForeignKey(Blah2)
```

So what would that nested subquery in SQLAlchemy look like? I already did:

```py
obj = Blah3.query.filter_by(id=1).one_or_none()
assert obj.blah2.blah1_id == 1
```

But that requires more queries plus all I really need is do do an `EXISTS` subquery and really the entire thing should be an `EXISTS`. Any ideas how to jam pack all this into one query on SQLAlchemy? Thanks!

Comment: Ah here you have the models. Assuming you had set up the `relationship` attributes you'd just nest the EXISTS producing expressions: `Blah3.query.filter(Blah3.blah2.has(Blah2.blah1.has(attr=1)))`

Comment: Thank you @IljaEverilä !!

Comment: The other option would be to use joins: `Blah3.query.join(Blah2).join(Blah1).filter(Blah1.attr == 1)`.